# AJAX displays undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a html page that have these codes, what this does is it displays the list of employees residing in the database

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var employeeList = $('#EmployeeList');

        $('#DisplayEmp').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'api/employees',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    employeeList.empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index,val){ 
                        var fullName = val.employee_Name;
                        employeeList.append('<li>' + fullName + '</li>')
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="DisplayEmp" type="button" value="Display Employees" />
    <input id="ClearEmp" type="button" value="Clear Employees" />
    <ul id="EmployeeList"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to jquery so I am not really familiar with the codes. But when I ran the program it displays `undefined` which is I dont have any Idea in its confusing. I checked my codes one by one but still failed to find the problem.

this is my model class

```
 public partial class tblEmployee
{
    public int Employee_ID { get; set; }
    public string Employee_Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Department_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Salary { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a controller named `Employees` when I run the API through `URI` it displays the list of employees properly.

EDIT 1
Here is the response of the server
[image]

EDIT 2
Here is my controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetEmployees(string gender = "All")
    {
        using (EmployeeDBEntities employeeEntity = new EmployeeDBEntities())
        {
            switch (gender.ToLower())
            {
                case "all":
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, employeeEntity.tblEmployees.ToList());
                case "male":
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, employeeEntity.tblEmployees.Where(e => e.Gender.ToLower() == gender).ToList());
                case "female":
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, employeeEntity.tblEmployees.Where(e => e.Gender.ToLower() == gender).ToList());
                default:
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Value for gender must be All,Male or Female" + gender + "is invalid.");
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 3:
 Find it weird, as you can see my model class have a property `Age` so I tried using that property `val.Age` and it still displays `undefined` however if I replaced it with `val.age` notice the lowercase it displays the correct data. But when I tried it with `val.Employee_Name` to `val.employee_name` it still displays undefined.

Comment: Can you add an sample ajax response to your question?

Comment: `$.ajax` return plain text... So either convert to JSON using `$.parseJSON` or directly using $.getJSON

Comment: @MohammadHamedani what response? all it displays is when I run the program `Employees.html` and clik the button to display the employees it displays `undefined`

Comment: @SanjiBukai what do you mean? can you provide the syntax?

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia Replace in your 4th line of script replace `$.ajax({` with `$.getJSON({`

Comment: Add `console.log(date)` in `success` function and share output of it. (I mean: `success: function (data) { console.log(date);  employeeList.empty();`)

Comment: Changing the method to `.getJSON()` seems not necessary since you correctly set `dataType: 'json'`.. As others said, share the response data.

Comment: Response from `api/employees` or your controller. @VianOjedaGarcia

Comment: @MohammadHamedani how to see the logs? did you mean `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: Your response is XML and not json! @VianOjedaGarcia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out how to display the right value I used `val.employee_Name` I lowered case the `Employee` can someone explain it to me? Ill accept it as an answer

Comment: It's so strange. Please share your final ajax request for improve my knowledge! thanks.

Comment: @MohammadHamedani what do you mean request? my ajax code? is that what you mean? im so sorry, I dont know a thing about ajax, im just starting to learn Web API, and this is the only AJAX code that i know.

Comment: I mean ajax codes that works and you added in your question.($.ajax...). Thanks

Comment: @MohammadHamedani please see my edit versio nof codes. Just changed the `val.Employee_Name` to `val.employee_Name`

Answer (score 0):

Change it this way to see the errors from your server:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'api/employees',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function (data) {
    employeeList.empty();
    var x = $(data).find('ArrayOftblEmployee');
    $.each(x, function (index, val){ 
      var fullName = val.find('tblEmployee').find('Employee_Name');
      employeeList.append('<li>' + fullName + '</li>')
    });
  }
});
```

Your jquery code seems ok. My suggestion is that you work with your "model class" in your server.

Comment: I added your code, how to see the logs? coz nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You have xml response, so you can use following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var employeeList = $('#EmployeeList');

        $('#DisplayEmp').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'api/employees',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function (data) {
                    employeeList.empty();
                    var ArrayOftblEmployee = data.find('ArrayOftblEmployee');
                    $.each(data, function (index,val){ 
                        var fullName = val.find('tblEmployee').find('Employee_Name');
                        employeeList.append('<li>' + fullName + '</li>')
                    });
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="DisplayEmp" type="button" value="Display Employees" />
    <input id="ClearEmp" type="button" value="Clear Employees" />
    <ul id="EmployeeList"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does nothing bruh, when I replaced the `dataType:json` with `dataType:xml` it does not display anything. However after trying something I find it weird that `val.Age` displays `undefined` but when I use `val.age` it display the correct data.

Comment: this seems to become a mess now